# Debian 11: Computer to computer network creates erronious routing entry?

Tags: networking, debian

I have two computers, one of which is a Debian 11 machine and the other of which is a Windows 10 machine. They are both connected to a 1GbE network. Their IP addresses are obtained via DHCP. The network is 192.168.2.0/24.

These machines also have additional 10GbE network cards in them. They are connected together directly via a single cable.

On the Debian 11 side, I have configured this network interface using XFCE Network Manager. The screenshots below give details of the current configuration.

I am confused by the output of `ip route`, which has *two* default routes. One of which is for the `192.168.2.0/24` network, and the other is for the `192.168.20.0/24` network.

Both machines can ping each other, but the Debian 11 machine no longer has access to the wider internet. It seems like packets are being routed to the Windows 10 machine by default, and that this machine (because it isn't configured as a router) doesn't know where to send these packets destined for other networks.

[image: ipv4 settings]

[image: ethernet settings]

[image: priority settings]

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting both machines seems to have solved the problem. The output of `ip route` is now as expected on both machines, with only one default route, and that default route being the one for the interface which is connected to my router.

As far as I am aware there are no errors in the above configuration, despite the yellow box for the ipv4 gateway. (If this should be some other value please let me know.)

At one point I had entered a value into this field, so it is possible this initiated a routing loop which rebooting the machines then solved.